# what is the replacement for this ES6 arrow var matchLang = (route) => new RegExp('^' + route.replace('*', '.*')).test(browLoc)?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

```
var matchLang = (route) => new RegExp('^' + route.replace('*', '.*')).test(browLoc)
```

What is the replacement for this ES6 arrow function in IE ?f anyone knows please help

Answer (score 0):

```
var matchLang = function(route){ 
    return new RegExp('^' + route.replace('*', '.*')).test(browLoc)
}
```

Comment: You are missing a return statement before new.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions

Your code is equals to the follow:

```
var matchLang = function (route) {
    return new RegExp('^' + route.replace('*', '.*')).test(browLoc)
}
```